# How to substring records with variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has a column with doc locations, such as AA/BB/CC/EE

I am trying to get only one of these parts, lets say just the CC part (which has variable length). Until now I've tried as follows:

```
SELECT RIGHT(doclocation,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(doclocation),0)-1) 
FROM Table 
WHERE doclocation LIKE '%CC %'
```

But I'm not getting the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use PARSENAME function like this,

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = 'AA/BB/CC/EE'

SELECT PARSENAME(replace(@s, '/', '.'), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PARSENAME` function is used to get the specified part of an object name, and should not used for this purpose, as it will only parse strings with max 4 objects (see SQL Server PARSENAME documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx))
SQL Server 2016 has a new function `STRING_SPLIT`, but if you don't use SQL Server 2016 you have to fallback on the solutions described here: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Answer (score 0):

This is painful to do in SQL Server.  One method is a series of string operations.  I find this simplest using `outer apply` (unless I need subqueries for a different reason):

```
select *
from t outer apply
     (select stuff(t.doclocation, 1, patindex('%/%/%', t.doclocation), '') as doclocation2) t2 outer apply
     (select left(tt.doclocation2), charindex('/', tt.doclocation2) as cc
     ) t3;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The question is not clear I guess. Can you please specify which value you need? If you need the values after CC, then you can do the `CHARINDEX` on "CC". Also the query does not seem correct as the string you provided is "AA/BB/CC/EE" which does not have a space between it, but in the query you are searching for space `WHERE doclocation LIKE '%CC %'`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(doclocation,CHARINDEX('CC',doclocation)+2,LEN(doclocation)) 
FROM Table 
WHERE doclocation LIKE '%CC %'
```